# C++ Copy a vector of pair<int,int> to a vector<int>

Tags: c++, stl, struct, stdvector, std-pair

I've a vector of pair which I need to copy them linearly to a vector of ints. I've the following code which works well, but I'm not sure if it's safe considering struct padding issues in C++.

```
std::vector < std::pair<int, int> > test_vector;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    test_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(i,i*5));
}
std::vector<int> int_vec(test_vector.size() * 2);
std::copy(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&(*test_vector.begin())),reinterpret_cast<int*>(&(*test_vector.end())),int_vec.begin());
```

Now, my question is - Is the above code safe? If not, is there an elegant way to do it without writing a loop?

Comment: This is more elegant than writing a loop? Just asking, that's all.

Comment: I suppose you could technically return the resulting vector from a call to `std::accumulate`, and the algorithm name would make sense in a way.

Comment: When you think about it, it's just two lines. Actually just one line if I use back_inserter instead of assigning it in advance. It's always more elegant to use a single line of code using existing stl algorithms than writing error prone loops. (In my opinion). Especially if it is a part of another routine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)  and a lambda function ?

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::transform(test_vector.begin(), test_vector.end(), std::back_inserter(v), 
               [&v](const std::pair<int, int> &p) 
               { v.push_back( p.first);
                 return p.second ;});
```

If you can't use C++11, and probably "hate" doing linear copying using loops

You can use functor like:

```
struct X{
    X(std::vector<int> &x) :v(x){}
    int operator () (const std::pair<int, int> &p)
    {
        v.push_back(p.first);
        return p.second;
    }
    std::vector<int> &v;
};

std::vector<int> v; //Final vector

std::transform(test_vector.begin(), 
               test_vector.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(v), 
               X(v));

std::vector<int> ::iterator it;

for(it=v.begin() ; it!=v.end() ;++it)
  std::cout<<*it<<" ";
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, not yet using C++11 (VS2008). But I can use Boost. Care to write one using boost?

Comment: @rwb You can write a functor class instead to use in old C++.

Comment: Yes, I can of course write a functor. But wanted just to know if there is a  different way, even it means using Boost.

Answer (score 1):

A `reinterpret_cast` is usually bad news. Wouldn't you be better off reserve()ing enough space in the destination vector and then calling `std::for_each` on the source vector of pairs and then have the function/lambda push_back both first and second into the destination vector ?

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, my knowledge of lambdas is very limited. Is there a way to push_back both first and second elements in one call without using a functor object? I'm still using C++03 standard, but I can use Boost as an alternative.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it in one call without something like what you already had. A functor is the safest/most portable way that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned about structure padding issues, but I think you haven't really faced the central assumption that your code is making:

> Can I treat a `std::pair<int, int>` as an array of two integers, with the `.first` being the first element in the array and `.second` being the second element?

From a "correctness" point of view, I'd say "no". You've identified padding issues, but there's also the ordering of the fields. There's really no guarantee that `.first` has a lower memory address than `.second`.

From a "practical" point of view, I'd be quite surprised your that code did not work. *[ Edit: Neil has pointed out a concrete example where there are padding issues; so color me surprised. Besides being "bad form", I now consider the code broken in practice. ]*

As for a solution, you can use `for_each` with a custom action that pushes both elements of the pair (untested code)

```
struct action {
    action ( vector<int> & target ) : t_(target) {}
    void operator () ( const pair &p ) const 
        { t_.push_back(p.first); t_.push_back(p.second); }
private:
    vector<int> &t_;
}

for_each ( test_vector.begin(), test_vector.end(), action(v));
```

Comment: -9999999999999999 for suggesting this is ok practically.

Comment: Sorry if I gave that impression; my attempt was to say that the code would, in fact, accomplish what the OP was attempting - not that it was a good idea.

Comment: Except when it doesn't due to padding issues.

Comment: Right. Do you have an example where padding issues cause it to fail?

Comment: int is 32-bits and structures are padded to 64-bits.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I did post in my question that my code works but I wasn't sure if it is correct.

Comment: Actually maybe I am wrong. If structs are padded to 32-bits, two 16-bit shorts still fit into 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any fanciness for this problem. A simple for loop will do, especially if you can't use C++11

```
std::vector < std::pair<int, int> > test_vector;
std::vector<int> int_vec; int_vec.reserve(test_vector.size() * 2);
for (std::vector < std::pair<int, int> >::const_iterator it = test_vector.begin(), end_it = test_vector.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
{
    int_vec.push_back(it->first);
    int_vec.push_back(it->second);
}
```

Comment: A loop is simple and using anything else might be an overkill, but I was curious if it's possible using stl algorithms.